# MVC C# binding a linq to sql object with a one to many relation for the edit page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a basic mvc edit page for one of my linq to sql object called AVC which has a one to many relation to MemberKommuns and i want to display a list of all the MemberKommuns for the user so they can select the one they want.

The get function for the edit page

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    AVC avc = DatabaseManager.GetAVC(id); //get avc by id

    List<MemberKommun> kommuns = DatabaseManager.GetMemberKommuns(); //get all MemberKommuns

    //turn list into list of listItems for the drop down control
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < kommuns.Count; i++)
    {
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Selected = kommuns[i].Id == avc.MemberKommunId,
            Text = kommuns[i].Name,
            Value = kommuns[i].Id.ToString(),
        });
    }

    //send data to page as tuple
    Tuple<AVC, List<SelectListItem>> data = new Tuple<AVC, List<SelectListItem>>(avc, listItems);
    return View(data);
}
```

Shortened version of the html page

```
@model Tuple<AVC, List<SelectListItem>>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Item1.Id)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Item1.MemberKommunId, Model.Item2, new { size = 10 })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item1.Name)
<input type="submit" value="Edit" />
```

The post version for the edit page. a dummy function that just prints the avc as json

```
[HttpPost]
public string Edit(AVC viewData)
{
    return Helper.ToJson(viewData);
}
```

Json data

```
{ 
"Id": "3ad40e34-c660-4226-87e0-fd7c2dca0e8d", 
"MemberKommunId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", 
"Name": null, 
}
```

As shown by the json data, id get binded correctly but the rest of the field gets their default values. In the full code the AVC have several more fields and all of them get their default value, i removed them for clarity.

I have no need to get the list of MemberKommuns back in the post function. How can i get the binder to fill in the rest of the AVC in the post function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your input fields are prefixed with some `Item1` and `Item2` properties which I highly doubt are present in your `AVC` model. The reason why your input field names are prefixed with them is because you used a Tuple class as view model.

So for this to work get rid of this Tuple stuff and write a real view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public AVC AVC { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action will populate:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    AVC avc = DatabaseManager.GetAVC(id); //get avc by id

    List<MemberKommun> kommuns = DatabaseManager.GetMemberKommuns(); //get all MemberKommuns

    //turn list into list of listItems for the drop down control
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < kommuns.Count; i++)
    {
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Selected = kommuns[i].Id == avc.MemberKommunId,
            Text = kommuns[i].Name,
            Value = kommuns[i].Id.ToString(),
        });
    }

    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.AVC = avc;
    model.Items = listItems;
    return View(model);
}
```

Now your view could be strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AVC.Id)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AVC.MemberKommunId, Model.Items, new { size = 10 })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AVC.Name)
<input type="submit" value="Edit" />
```

and your POST controller action will of course take the view model as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Edit(MyViewModel model)
{
    return Helper.ToJson(model.AVC);
}
```

And now everything will bind nice and dandy.

Comment: Thanks that works. I dont understand what the difference is thou, wont the tuple look exactly like MyViewModel when i put an AVC and List<SelectListItem> in as the generics?

Comment: No, it won't look the same. Look at the generated markup and more specifically the names of your input fields. Also your controller action cannot take a Tuple as argument because the corresponding properties (Item1 and Item2) do not have setters meaning that the default model binder will never be able to set them. So stay away from those Tuples and use view models.